# Using 2.0 speakers in 2.1 sub-woofer can this be done?

Tags: speakers

I am having a speakers 2.1 i.e. it has a Sub-woofer and two satellite speakers with it but the problem is that one of my satellite speakers out of two is not working can I use 2.0 speakers with the Sub-woofer I am having..... since I only want two satellite speakers no Sub-woofer any idea about it..I am using altec lansing series 100 121i speakers.

Comment: You really need to post more information, make and model of hardware, operating system, etc

Comment: What do you mean by buffer? Subwoofer? Typically 2.1 means "two satellite speakers and one subwoofer"

Comment: I edited my post please help me out in this ..

Answer (score 0):

assuming that this image is the same as the back of your particular speaker system it should be possible to get your own speakers and connect them to the sub-woofer (remove any end plugs if necessary, if you aren't worried about not being able to return them later).

[image: Altec Lansing 121i]

Comment: Thanks Xantec this is my 2.1 speakers...but when I connect other satellite speakers to this sub woofer will it work ...thats the real problem..

Comment: Hey just tell me which type of connector I should use which is having input as wire and output as pin

Comment: @FrozenKing i don't know of a specific connector like that. basically it would just be length of speaker wire that has a male plug soldered on to one end